# if statement whilst slicing

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

I have a number of lists that I am slicing, such that (using example data):

```
midpoint = [[0.2], [0.5], [0.6]]
Values = [[0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8], [0.2,0.3,0.5,0.7], [0.2,0.5,0.6,0.9]]
numbers = numpy.arange(0, len(Values), 1)
```

I then have a loop that finds the index position from `numbers` of the first value that is greater or less than the `midpoint` value. I have:

```
for i in range(len(Values)):
    indexgtr = numbers[Values[i]>=midpoint[i]][-1] # The position of the first number larger than the midpoint
    indexlt = numbers[Values[i]<=midpoint[i]][0] # The position of the first number larger than the midpoint
```

I then use these index positions to return values from some other lists that I have.

The problem I have is that sometimes there is no value greater or less than the midpoint so `indexgtr` or `indexlt` return an empty list `[]` and I get the error `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`.

Is there something that I could add that would catch this and substitute a value of 0 into the empty list?

Comment: The error that I obtain is not the same as yours, and the error I obtain running your code is what I expected. First, the expression `Values[i] >= midpoint[i]` is comparing a `list` to a scalar value, and in Python 2 this returns just a boolean (Python 3 gives unorderable types error). So if it is `True`, you are accessing `numbers[1]` and if it `False` you are accessing `numbers[0]`, and *then* trying to further access either `numbers[1][-1]` or `numbers[0][-1]`, which will give an error because `numbers[i]` is a scalar that cannot be indexed for each `i`.

Comment: The data above is just an example as my real data is very large and more complex to explain. I understand that it returns a boolean but its not simply `True` of `False`, its more `[True, True, True, False, False, False]` depending on the length of the list. This would then slice `numbers` appropriately and deliver me the index position `[0]` or `[-1]` as required, unless Im mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the desired results vectorizing and using [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) along the second axis:

```
>>> midpoint = np.array([[0.2], [0.5], [0.6], [0.3]])
>>> values = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8],
                       [0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
                       [0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9],
                       [0.3, 0.1, 0.8, 0.9]])

>>> (values > midpoint).argmax(axis=1) # indexgtr vectorized
array([1, 3, 3, 2]) # first >= occurrence for each row

>>> (values < midpoint).argmax(axis=1)
array([0, 0, 0, 1]) # first < occurrence for each row
```

---

**Note:** I've replaced the `<=` and `>=` with `<` and `>` to show better the vectorization result. Note that for the `<` case, the first row doesn't have any column smaller than `0.2`, yet `0` is returned (as it is the first occurrence for a row full of `False`s).

`.argmax(axis=1)` finds the position of the maximum value across the 2nd axis. As it is a boolean array, it returns the first `True` occurrence.

Comment: Good, but I think `np.argwhere` is more appropriate than `np.argmax`, since you are dealing with a bool array

Comment: @wim That would return the indices of ALL the elements (that satisfy the condition) and would require an additional postprocessing step to filter the first element of each row.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could express the tests:

```
for i in range(len(Values)):
    indexgtr = numbers[Values[i]>=midpoint[i]]
    if indexgtr.shape[0]==0:
        indexgtr = 0
    else:
        indexgtr = indexgtr[-1]
    indexlt = numbers[Values[i]<=midpoint[i]]
    if indexlt.shape[0]:       # alt expression
        indexlt = indexlt[0]
    else:
        indexlt = 0
    # indexlt = indexlt[0] if len(indexlt) else 0
```

They are all a bit wordy, but I don't think they are expensive.  You aren't doing anything with vectors here - except selecting subvalues from `numbers`.  Since `numbers` is sorted, you might also do something with `min` or `max` instead of selecting the first or last values.

Test expressions with things like:

```
In [39]: x=np.arange(0)
In [40]: x[0] if len(x) else 0
Out[40]: 0
```

I assume you are going on to do something with `indexgtr` and `indexlt` in this loop before moving on to the next `i`.

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing. I actually append the value to a new list, so like your answer I set up an `if` loop that checked the length of the array. If it was empty then i appended a value of 0.0, otherwise I ran my code. It too is wordy, but its not expensive.